# Windows 7 Environment Variable to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

Tags: .net, windows-7, batch-file, environment-variables

I need to create a batch file that run MSBuild.exe

I assumed that I could just call MSBuild, but when I do it does know that program.

MSBuild.exe lives in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319".  But I would rather not hard code that value.

Is there an environment variable in Windows 7 that will point to that location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the shortcut installed with visual studio 2010 that opens up the command prompt for Visual Studio x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt (2010) you will see:

```
%comspec% /k ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86_amd64
```

You should be able use that directly and then start MSBuild without issue without knowing the exact location.

Comment: Yes, this is what the Visual Studio Command Prompt is for. You could set up your command prompt the same way if you like.

Comment: Solid answer. Thank you very much!  (Just as an fyi, I had to lose the "x86_amd64" part for it to work.)